# Forcing WM_NCHITTEST to return HTCAPTION, with a custom cursor..?

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, message, mouse-cursor

I have created a borderless window that uses a `wndProc()` function that forces the `WM_NCHITTEST case` to return `HTCAPTION;`, which allows the user to drag the window, no matter where his cursor is located.
The problem is that I have set up a custom cursor, but with the abovementioned method, the cursor is always set back to `IDC_ARROW`.
How do I fix this?
EDIT: I've also tried using `SetCursor()` in the `WM_NCHITTEST case`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the WM_SETCURSOR message to override the cursor.  The LOWORD of lParam indicates the hit test code, the one that you altered with the WM_NCHITTEST handler.  This worked well:

```
static HCURSOR CustomCursor;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_NCHITTEST: {
        LRESULT result = DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        if (result == HTCLIENT) result = HTCAPTION;             
        return result;
    }
    case WM_SETCURSOR: 
        if (LOWORD(lParam) == HTCAPTION) {
            SetCursor(CustomCursor);
            return TRUE;
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    // etc...
}
```

Initialize CustomCursor in your window init.  Say:

```
CustomCursor = LoadCursor(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_SIZEALL));
```

Comment: Ehm.. I'm not sure what's going on here, but my `WndProc` looks completely different.. It's more like this:
`LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_NCHITTEST:
            return HTCAPTION;
            break;
        // more cases
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}`

Comment: Eh.. Right.. no linebreaks in comments.. Well you should get the idea from that.

Comment: Works brilliantly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `SetCursor` in `WM_NCHITTEST` try to `SetCursor` in `WM_SETCURSOR` too.

Comment: I had to `return 1;` in `WM_SETCURSOR`, that's why your answer didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the correct way to set a cursor is to do it in response to the `WM_SETCURSOR` message. (Also see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/25/421707.aspx )

However, if you're handling a mouse drag where the mouse is captured, your window will not receive `WM_SETCURSOR` messages, and I think the only alternative is to set the cursor in the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` handler for that case.

Comment: I think that maybe you need to provide more details about exactly what you've been trying.

Comment: Exactly what I've told you. In my wndProc() I have a case: WM_NCHITTEST that always returns HTCAPTION. I've tried adding SetCursor() calls in there, in WM_SETCURSOR and in WM_MOUSEMOVE.

Comment: Descriptions are not a substitute for code.  Are you returning the right values in the message handlers?  If you're using ATL, are you setting the `bHandled` flag?  Is the mouse button down?  Are you using `SetCapture`? etc.